# rev() on lines of a matrix using apply induces a rotation?

Tags: r, matrix

rev is supposed to reverses it's argument, hence if we apply on the test matrix:

```
test<-matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6),nrow=2)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    3    5
[2,]    2    4    6
```

rev on the columns (2):

```
apply(test,2,rev)
```

We obtain:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    4    6
[2,]    1    3    5
```

But if we rev with apply on the lines (1)r, it rotates the matrix counterclock wise.

```
apply(test,1,rev)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    5    6
[2,]    3    4
[3,]    1    2
```

Is that me or that's a serious bug in apply and/or rev? I love the fact to have something that rotates a matrix but can I really rely on that :-/

Comment: This simply has to do with the way the results are combined into an array after applying `rev` to each row. Have a look at `?apply` and in particular the section "Value"

Comment: Nope. It's by design..  Have a look at a more simple example where you simply return the row `apply(test, 1, "[")`

Answer (score 1):

When possible, `apply()` returns the result of each application of the function in columns.

Note: This is simply a reformulation of the first sentence of the Value paragraph of the help, thanks konvas.